# Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null (i'm using window.onload - works in the book demo file)

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, So I've read a dozen threads (move script to bottom of doc, wrap function in onload etc) and can't figure this out. I'm working through exercises in murach's Javascript and jQuery. I have substituted some of my code for the author's code to try and eliminate user error, still it doesn't work.

**EDIT** The error occurs on lin 34 // if ($("first_name").value == "")

```
var $ = function (id)
{
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var joinList = function() 
{
    var email1 = $("email_address1").value;
    var email2 = $("email_address2").value;
    var isValid = true;
    if(email1 == "")
    {
        $("email_error1").innerHTML = "This field is required.";
        isValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("email_error1").innerHTML = "*";
    }
    if(email2 == "")
    {
        $("email_error2").innerHTML = "This field is required.";
        isValid = false;
    }
    else if (email1 !== email2)
    {
        $("email_error2").innerHTML = "Entries do NOT match.";
        isValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("email_error2").innerHTML = "*";
    }
    if ($("first_name").value == "")
    {
        $("first_name_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "This field is required.";
        isValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("first_name_error").innerHTML = "*";
    }
    if(isValid)
    {
        $("email_form").submit();
    }
}//end joinList

window.onload = function()
{
    $("join_list").onclick = joinList;
    $("email_address1").focus();
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Join our mailing list!</title>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src = "email_list.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
    <h1> Join our e-mail list today!</h1>
        <form id = "email_form" name = "email_form" action = "join.html" method = "get">
            <label for = "email_address1">Email Address:</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "email_address1" name = "email_address1" placeholder = "type email here">
            <span id = "email_error1">*</span><br>

            <label for = "email_address2">Re-enter Email Address:</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "email_address2" name = "email_address1" placeholder = "type email here">
            <span id = "email_error2">*<span><br>

            <label for = "first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "first_name" name = "first_name">
            <span id = "first_name_error">*</span><br>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type = "button" id = "join_list" value = "Join our list">
        </form>
    <section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<span id = "email_error2">*<span><br>
```

should be

```
<span id = "email_error2">*</span><br>
                            ^
```

the problem with your code because of that was, after the innerHTML of that span was written to, it removed ALL of the html after that all the way to the `</form>` ... therefore the first_name checking went awry

Comment: omg I can't believe I spent 4 hours scanning and comparing code and didn't see that..thank you sir. Also is this something that I could have caught with jSLint? I feel like there must be an easier way to find little things like that other than inspecting element and switching to console view.

Comment: jslint wont, I don't know off hand what will - looking at the page in "Inspector" in firefox showed it for me